# Crack password protected zip file with pkcrack

Tags: password-cracking, zip

I have `allfiles.zip` contains only file `allfiles.exe` and is password protected. I heard about `pkcrack`, it is possible to get the file from a zip file which is encrypted if we have some part of encrypted zip.(Correct me if I'm wrong)

So, with that statement, I have add a plaintext file(`words.txt`) to `allfiles.zip`, created another zip file `wordfiles.zip` which contains only plaintext file `words.txt` and run `pcrack`.(You can see below step-by-step)

1. Initially we have password protected zip

```
allfiles.zip
  -> allfiles.exe
```

2. Add a dummy plaintext file to `allfiles.zip`. Now the file `allfiles.zip` contains 2 files

```
allfiles.zip
  -> allfiles.exe
  -> words.txt
```

3. Create a zip file contains only `words.txt`

```
wordfiles.zip
  -> words.txt
```

4. Run pkcrack on those files

```
./pkcrack -C allfiles.zip -c words.txt -P wordfiles.zip -p words.txt -d allfiles.exe1 -a
Warning! Plaintext is longer than Ciphertext!
Files read. Starting stage 1 on Thu Feb 28 11:39:48 2019
Generating 1st generation of possible key2_255982 values...done.
Found 4194304 possible key2-values.

---OUTPUT REMOVED----

Lowest number: 93 values at offset 246121
Done. Left with 93 possible Values. bestOffset is 246121.
Stage 1 completed. Starting stage 2 on Thu Feb 28 11:40:10 2019
Stage 2 completed. Starting zipdecrypt on Thu Feb 28 11:40:15 2019
No solutions found. You must have chosen the wrong plaintext.
Finished on Thu Feb 28 11:40:15 2019
```

Is this a right way to crack? What is the best way to crack?(Other than `fcrackzip`)

Comment: I think you're confusing a known-plaintext attack (KPA) with cracking a random file. So zip 1 contains two files: the file you want to crack and your known plaintext (you called it words.txt). Zip 2 contains only the plaintext (words.txt). In a KPA, the known file in zip 1 would be encrypted and zip 2 is only so pkcrack knows what the plaintext version of it is. But because you never encrypted words.txt in zip 1 (since you don't have the password), you are basically giving pkcrack two identical files, so it cannot find any solutions.

Comment: In layman's terms, you're using an attack that you cannot do because you don't have the plaintext of `allfiles.exe`. If you did, then you could recover the encryption pattern (the 'keystream') and apply it to other files, of which you might not have the plaintext (e.g. if `allfiles.zip` contains another file which you don't yet know the contents of, but it doesn't: there is only `allfiles.exe`).

Comment: @Luc Understood. I just came to know whatever I was doing is not possible

Comment: I realized what I said is a little too long for a comment, so I tried to write it in a more structured way as an answer. Sorry I can't help you further!

Comment: your `words.txt` has to be encrypted in a same way as `allfiles.exe` to make this trick work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PKCrack](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~conrad/krypto/pkcrack.html) does a *known-plaintext attack* (KPA). So you need to know the plaintext of a file in the zip archive before you can decrypt other files in the same zip file. But there are no other files in your archive, so you cannot do the attack.

One might ask "What is the point of doing a KPA, if you already need to know the answer?" Well, imagine you have a zip archive with the files "passwords.txt" and "usernames.txt". You could have obtained the plaintext of "usernames.txt" through other means (like asking the sysadmin) because it's not secret. By comparing the known contents of the usernames file with the encrypted version, you can (using pkcrack) recover the [keystream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystream). Then, you can use that keystream to decrypt the other file ("passwords.txt"). Note that you never learn the password, but you can decrypt the other file(s) in the archive.

In your case, "passwords.txt" is "allfiles.exe" (the file you don't know the contents of, but you want to decrypt it). To try to simulate the attack, you added "words.txt" to the zip archive, but you can't encrypt "words.txt" with the same keystream as "allfiles.exe" because you don't know the password (so you can't generate that keystream). So the attack is impossible this way.